# How to download a jar with a different name using Maven Dependency plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

In my Maven repository I have two jars. `app.jar` and `app-exec.jar`. I'm trying to download `app-exec.jar` using Maven Dependency plugin

If I'll just run it with:

`-Dartifact=com.example.app:LATEST`

it will download `app.jar`

I tried to add `-DartifactId=app-exec.jar` but it seems to be ignored.

How can I direct the plugin to download the other jar?

Thanks

Comment: The usual format for artifacts is `groupID:artifactId:version`. in your example you don't seem to have the id, only group and version. Have you tried with `-Dartifact=com.example.app:app-exec:LATEST`?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to find/resolve artifact.: Could not find artifact com.example.app:LATEST:app-exec in nexus (http://nexus.example.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try `com.example.app:app-exec:LATEST` or `com.example.app:LATEST:app-exec`?

Comment: `com.example.app:app-exec:LATEST`

Comment: The file in the repository looks like this: `app-1.0-20210107.094335-109-exec.jar`

Comment: `exec` is a classifier so you have to use it `mvn dependency:get -DgroupId=org.apache.maven -DartifactId=maven-core -Dversion=2.2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dclassifier=sources `....

Comment: @khmarbaise, Thanks! I see it appears in my `.m2` dir. How can I get it to the working directory instead? (jar only)

Comment: See the docs https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html and use the `copy` goal instead...